# Disks application not reading SMART data correctly?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, smart

One of my computers has an older Seagate 750GB HDD.

I checked on the SMART data with the included Disks program this afternoon, and I found that it had:

- A "seek error rate" **441 Million**
- A "read error rate" of **91 Million**

Now, my first thought was: *"I'm on borrowed time with this HDD"*

**BUT** - then I noticed - there are ZERO relocated sectors, and ZERO unrecoverable read errors. Not to mention, the "overall assessment" is "OK".

Sooooo.... is there a bug in the SMART function of the included Disks program, or is my HDD rapidly dying?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64.

---

Here's the output from `smartctl`:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   115   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       91360976
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   095   094   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   080   080   020    Old_age   Always       -       20501
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   086   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       441627511
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   087   087   000    Old_age   Always       -       11433
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   090   090   020    Old_age   Always       -       10247
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       62
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   071   059   045    Old_age   Always       -       29 (Min/Max 29/29)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   029   041   000    Old_age   Always       -       29 (0 16 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   045   039   000    Old_age   Always       -       91360976
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       222908802698505
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3543376747
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       294732052
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S.M.A.R.T. data is not known for being user-friendly. When evaluating the information from the output of `smartctl`, the key to remember is that:

> Each metric is considered to have failed **when `WORST` is below `THRESH`**.

In your example, each row's `WORST` is greater than `THRESH` and therefore none of the metrics are indicating failure. Notice also that the `WHEN_FAILED` column is empty, confirming that none of the metrics have reached the critical point.

Also note that raw read errors are common during normal operation and not an exceptional situation.